# Using regexp to index a file for imenu, performance is unacceptable

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm producing a function for `imenu-create-index-function`, to index a source code module, for [csharp-mode.el](http://code.google.com/p/csharpmode/downloads/list)

It works, but delivers completely unacceptable performance. Any tips for fixing this?

### The Background

I looked at js.el, which is the rebadged "espresso" now included, since v23.2, into emacs. It indexes Javascript files very nicely, does a good job with anonymous functions and various coding styles and patterns in common use.  For example, in javascript one can do:

```
(function() {
    var x = ... ; 
    function foo() {
       if (x == 1) ...
    }
})();
```

...to define a scope where `x` is "private" or inaccessible from other code. This gets indexed nicely by js.el, using regexps, and it indexes the inner functions (anonymous or not) within that scope also. It works quickly.  A big module can be indexed in less than a second.

I tried following a similar approach in csharp-mode, but it's quite a bit more complicated. In Js, everything that gets indexed is a function.  So the starting regex is "function" with some elaboration on either end.  Once an occurrence of the `function` keyword is found, then there are 4 - 8 other regexps that get tried via `looking-at` - the number depends on settings. One nice thing about js mode is that you can turn on or off regexps for various coding styles, to speed things along I suppose. The default "styles" work for most of the code I tried.

This doesn't work in csharp-mode. It *works*, but it performs poorly enough to make it not very usable. I think the reason for this is that

- there is no single marker keyword in C#, as `function` behaves in javascript. In C# I need to look for namespace, class, struct, interface, enum, and so on.
- there's a great deal of flexibility with which csharp constructs can be defined. As one example, a class can define base classes as well as implemented interfaces.  Another example: The return type for a method isn't a simple word-like string, but can be something messy like `Dictionary<String, List<String>>` . The index routine needs to handle all those cases, and capture the matches. This makes it run sloooooowly.
- I use a lot of `looking-back`.  The marker I use in the current approach is the open curly brace. Once I find one of those, I use `looking-back` to determine if the curly is a class, interface, enum, method, etc. I read that `looking-back` can be slow; I'm not clear on how much slower it is than, say, `looking-at`.
- once I find an open-close pair of curlies, I call `narrow-to-region` in order to index what's inside. not sure if this is will kill performance or not. I suspect that it is not the main culprit, because the perf problems I see happen in modules with one namespace and 2 or 3 classes, which means narrow gets called 3 or 4 times total.

### What's the Question?

My question is: *do you have any tips for speeding up imenu-like indexing in a C# buffer?*

I'm considering:

- avoiding `looking-back`.  I don't know exactly how to do this because when `re-search-forward` finds, say, the keyword `class`, the cursor is already in the middle of a class declaration.  `looking-back` seems essential.
- instead of using open-curly as the marker, use the keywords like enum, interface, namespace, class
- avoid `narrow-to-region`

any hard advice? Further suggestions?

Something I've tried and I'm not really enthused about re-visiting:  building a wisent-based parser for C#, and relying on semantic to do the indexing.  I found semantic to be very very very (etc) difficult to use, hard to discover, and problematic. I had semantic working for a while, but then upgraded to v23.2, and it broke, and I never could get it working again. Simple things - like indexing the namespace keyword - took a very long time to solve.  I'm very dissatisfied with it and don't want to try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know C# syntax, and without looking at your elisp it's hard to give an answer, but here goes anyway.

`looking-back` can be deadly slow.  It's the first thing I'd experiment with.  One thing that helps a lot is using the `limit` arg to, say, restrict your search to the beginning of the current line.  A different approach is when you hit the open curly do `backward-char` then `backward-sexp` (or whatever) to get to the front of the previous word, then use `looking-at`.

Using keywords to search around instead of open curly is probably what I would have done.  Maybe something like `(re-search-forward "\\(enum\\|interface\\|namespace\\|class\\)[ \t\n]*{" nil t)` then using `match-string-no-properties` on the first capture group to see which of the keywords was found.  This might help with the `looking-back` problem as well.

I don't know how expensive `narrow-to-region` is, but could be avoided by when you find a open curly do `save-excursion` `forward-sexp` and keep `point` as a limit for the current iteration of your (I assume recursive) searches.